# Is there a name for deformation-based maps?

Tags: cartography, representation

I have already seen maps using deformation to visualize information. For example, this map shows temporal distance between some French cities when traveling by train: http://www.nf-ameublement-pro.com/sc/images/new/newsletter/septembre/carte_france.jpg

Is there a name for this kind of map? Also, is this type of map available in any GIS software?

Comment: The effect of the [TGV](http://www.raileurope.com/train-faq/european-trains/tgv/how-to-book.html) (especially Paris-Dijon-Lyon) is particularly pronounced in this illustration.

Comment: Trimaps (http://trimaps.com) enables to use that kind of maps in application and geolocalize on it. Note that you have to come with the map...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is called a [distance cartogram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartogram).  Some add-ons for ArcGIS have been produced to create *area* cartograms.  Mark Newman provides free [GIS-independent software](http://www-personal.umich.edu/~mejn/cart/) to implement his area cartogram method.  Methods of creating distance cartograms are known in statistics as [multidimensional scaling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multidimensional_scaling) (MDS).  I do not know of any GIS software that implements MDS, but it's available in full-featured statistical packages like [Stata](http://www.stata.com/) (commercial) and [R](http://www.statmethods.net/advstats/mds.html) (free).

Answer (score 12):

**Anamorphic map** or even **cartographic anamorphosis** are also used.

[Scapetoad](http://scapetoad.choros.ch/) does it.

Answer (score 7):

Scapetoad produces area cartograms, not distance cartograms.
You can produce distance cartograms with **Darcy** 
You can download the software (Java program) : https://sourceforge.net/projects/jdarcy/

Before using Darcy you have to transform the distance matrix in coordinates (multi dimensional scaling). In R the simple function for MDS is cmdscale.
Now, Darcy implements this R function.

Answer (score 6):

There is another type which is called "[Cartogram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartogram)"
QGIS has a plugin to generate cartograms.
This one shows the size of the country based on GDP:
[image: Cartogram of "GDP per capita" by country, 2000]

Comment: The original map is at http://maps.grida.no/go/graphic/world_economy_cartogram (Philippe Rekacewicz, UNEP/GRID-Arendal, Vladimir S. Tikunov).  @Pablo appears to be correct but *the legend title is wrong* (and so is the description on the Web site): apparently, the map areas are proportional to GDP and the *colors* denote GDP *per capita.*

Answer (score 0):

I've found the DistanceCartogram plugin (https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/author/Matthieu%2520Viry/) for QGIS. But it keeps getting lots of errors when I try to use it.