# Weighting Point Data whilst performing a Near analysis

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.2, nearest-neighbor

I am struggling to work out how I can assign weights to my points (airports), So far I have carried out a Near fuction so that all of my raster (output areas ) are assigned a point with its distance being recorded. How do I now weight the different points, due to other airports being larger than others? Any Ideas?

Comment: ArcMap 10.2.2 Software

Comment: How will the weight be used in subsequent analysis? Is the weight value considered in addition to proximity (locations near a large airport have higher value than locations near a small one)? Do you want larger airports to have larger service areas (sort of overriding the "actual" nearest airport)?

Comment: I want the larger airports to have a larger service area. The Airports have weights assigned to them, I just want the weights to be taken into account when assigning the output areas to airports

Comment: That's harder ;) Looking at this Question and its Answers may help you: [How can I create weighted Thiessen polygons?](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/17282/how-can-i-create-weighted-thiessen-polygons)