# How to draw boundaries to separate clusters?

Tags: software-recommendations, clustering, boundaries

I have used the R Project for Statistical Computing to make a map of clusters based on latitude and longitude by using the k-mean clustering.

Is there any software I can use to import the clusters into a map and draw boundaries between the cluster to create regions?

Also, for further analysis, I have some more data points.

Is there any software which I can use to identify which regions the data points (lon, lat) belongs to?

[image: cluster]

Answer (score 1):

Kmean separates the clusters based on Euclidian distance to centroids, so if you keep this logic you are looking for a Voronoi like algorithm around the centroids (mean lat and mean long) of each cluster.  This can be done with most softwares, here are 2 examples:

QGIS/GRASS: see [Is it possible to create Thiessen polygons around nodes in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/6971/is-it-possible-to-create-thiessen-polygons-around-nodes-in-qgis)

ArcGIS : [The drawing of Thiessen/Voronoi polygon boundaries - are the bisecting lines truly perpendicular?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/178157/the-drawing-of-thiessen-voronoi-polygon-boundaries-are-the-bisecting-lines-tru)

Note that you can also create such Voronoi map (not a cartographic map) within R: http://letstalkdata.com/2014/05/creating-voronoi-diagrams-with-ggplot/