# How to draw weighted voronoi polygons (thiessen) from points in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, voronoi-thiessen

I have a shapefile of polygons which have an amount of population, I need to divide each of these polygons into small ones with nearly equal population. So I thought attributing points on each area inside each polygon and attributing a weight depending on its density.

After that I have to draw voronoi polygons based on the points drawn before and their weights to get these small areas that should be equally populated.

I tried to draw them in qgis but all I get is polygons with equal weights.

How to draw weighted voronoi polygons in QGIS?

Comment: Related post (for Arcgis, but the answer might be useful anyway): [How can I create weighted Thiessen polygons?](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/17282/how-can-i-create-weighted-thiessen-polygons)

Comment: @ArMoraer the thing is that I'm only using Ubuntu, I guess Arcgis isn't going to help here. I'll try with R maybe if I get somewhere I'll post it. thanks for the link

Comment: If you read [the answer](http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/17290/64955) closely, you'll see that it doesn't really rely on Arcgis-specific tools. You can do the same thing in R, as you mentioned, or in QGIS (though it may require some scripting skills if you have a lot of input points).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thanks to ArMoraer's suggestions I made a little python script based on PyQGIS and GDAL to generate a weighted voronoi diagram from a vector layer.

[Here](https://github.com/HichamZouarhi/Weighted-Voronoi-PyQGIS.git) it is on github